# THREE.js raycaster intersectObject method returns no intersection when checking if point is inside mesh

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to check whether a point is inside a mesh or not. To do so, I use a raycaster, set it to the point's origin and if the ray intersects the mesh only once, it must be inside. Unfortunately, the intersectObject always returns no intersection, even in cases I know that the point is located inside the mesh.
The point's origin is given in world coordinates and the mesh's matrixWorld is up to date too. Also, I set the mesh.material.side to THREE.DoubleSide, so that the intersection from inside should be detected. I tried setting the recursive attribute to true as well, but as expected, this didn't have any effect (since the mesh is a box geometry). The mesh is coming from the Autodesk Forge viewer interface.
Here is my code:

```
mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
let vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
vertex.fromArray(positions, positionIndex);
vertex.applyMatrix4(matrixWorld);
const rayDirection = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1).normalize();
raycaster.set(vertex, rayDirection);
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
if (intersects.length % 2 === 1) {
   isPointInside = true;
}
```

The vertex looks like this (and it obviosly lies inside of the bounding box):

[image: vertex world coordinates]

The mesh is a box shaped room with the following bounding box:

[image: room bounding box]

The mesh looks like this:

[image: mesh]

The geometry of the mesh holds the vertices in the vb. After applying the world matrix, the mesh vertices are correct in world space. Here is a part of the vb list:

[image]

Why does the raycaster not return any intersection? Is the matrixWorld of the mesh taken into account when computing the intersections?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Try to set material `side: THREE.DoubleSide` and check intersections again.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks for your tip. As written in the text, I already did that. Also, the mesh's material side comes with THREE.DoubleSide set.

Comment: another option is to try to set the second parameter of `.intersectObject()` to `true` => `const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh, true);`

Comment: And one more thing, if you work with `mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array` directly, then, when you call `vertex.fromArray()`, `positionIndex` has to be multiplied with 3. And the alternative to this can be `vertex.fromBufferAttribute(mesh.geometry.attributes.position, positionIndex);`

Comment: Thanky you again for your hints! I already tried 'raycaster.intersectObject(mesh, true);', but it has no effect, which makes sence since the mesh is only one geometry (it is a room with a box shape). Regarding your second hint: The vertex coordinates look fine and are located inside the bounding box of the room. I will provide more information about the vertex, the mesh and its geometry in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Forge Viewer is based on three.js version R71, and it had to modify/reimplement some parts of the library to handle large and complex models (especially architecture and infrastructure designs), so `THREE.Mesh` objects might have a slightly different structure. In that case I'd suggest to raycast using Forge Viewer's own mechanisms, e.g., using `viewer.impl.rayIntersect(ray, ignoreTransparent, dbIds, modelIds, intersections);`.

Comment: Thank you Petr! Using the `viewer.impl.rayIntersect` function did the trick for me.